# AngularJS: How to change url in $http.get on select event

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have customers.php file which produce json data. List of json data are changing when we change variable in the url like this

`customers.php?var=5`

In AngularJS I have made html file with two separate part. 1st part is a select options with specific values. 2nd part is part who shows json data. It is clear that 2nd part use **$http.get(url)** where url is **customers.php?var=selected_number** in controller.

How can I change url in controller which use $http.get when user select specific options in < select > ... < / select > html file.

Footnote: Here is example of controller file

```
var Pajsije = angular.module('CodeOverflow', ['ngRoute']);

    Pajsije.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/viewa', {
            templateUrl : 'viewa.html',
            controller  : 'ViewAController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/viewb', {
            templateUrl : 'viewb.html',
            controller  : 'ViewBController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/viewc', {
            templateUrl : 'viewc.html',
            controller  : 'ViewCController'
        })
        .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/viewa'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
Pajsije.controller('ViewAController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Good look!';
});

Pajsije.controller('ViewBController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look about page.';
});

Pajsije.controller('ViewCController', ['$scope','$http', '$templateCache', function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

    $scope.myChange = function() {

    $http({method: 'GET', url: '../json-data/customers.php?idstudm=12', cache: $templateCache}).success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});

};

}]);
```

Comment: does select is also in `ViewCController` controller?

Comment: Yes, it does. The select options is in ViewCController.

Answer (score 0):

Try $rootScope to set the variable part of the URL in the controller whenever the selection in the UI (HTML Page) is made (querypart).

```
$rootScope.variableURL = "customers.php?var=" + $scope.selected_number;
```

Append this to the URL while sending $http request. Please inform me if I didn't understand the requirement properly.

 We already know that $rootScope is accessible across all controllers and can be used for smaller data carrying across controllers and services.

Comment: This will only initialize variableURL. I must create automatically variableURL on every select option.

Comment: This is good example [link](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/#/phones), but I don't know how to implement in my app.

Comment: You can use $scope.$watch(). See documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). This event gets fired everytime the value changes and calls the callback function provided by you, in which(callback function) you can use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use should bind selectbox to a scope model using `ngModel` directive and use this model in controller. Something like this:

```
<select ng-model="number" ng-change="myChange()">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3">10</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
Pajsije.controller('ViewCController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

    $scope.myChange = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../json-data/customers.php?idstudm=' + $scope.number,
            cache: $templateCache
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I put $http.get function in $scope.myChange it doesn't work.If I put out of $http.get function it work but I can not get different json-data when user select options in ng-model.

Comment: I mean I can't get the list of json-data when I use http.get function in $scope.myChange. When http.get function is outer of myChange, system show list with default value of json-data.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question. I think you have problem with separated files. I guess, because you are using AngularJS, you are using angular-route for automatic routing. So, for that reason you are probably using file like main.html which is include customers.html with routing management.
If in that file you have mechanism which will present data when routing happens, the data will not be presented in main file with ng-controller when user click on particular data to select. (not all data, only data which are in myChange function)

Best regards.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but why and not all data but only data which are in myChange function.